# Number Stored as Text in Excel created using DynamicReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using Dynamic Reports to create Reports and am able to create it. But the issue is that when i convert it to excel, the cell in the excel showing a warning as **Number Stored as Text**. Because of this no operation is possible.

Here is my code

```
File file = new File("c:/report.xls");

JasperXlsExporterBuilder xlsExporter = export.xlsExporter(file).setDetectCellType(true).setIgnorePageMargins(true)
                .setWhitePageBackground(false).setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);

report.addProperty(JasperProperty.EXPORT_XLS_FREEZE_ROW, "2").ignorePageWidth().ignorePagination().toXls(xlsExporter);
```

How to remove this error.

Comment: Have you seen [this wiki entry](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/excel-export-number-stored-text)?

Comment: @tobi6 but this is not the right way to do na. We cant tell the clients to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your code:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

[Source](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540379/automatically-converting-numbers-stored-text-numbers-when-export-excel-ireport)

**EDIT**

In the [Dynamic Reports samples](http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/excelreport2), the report variable also sets the following. This could help depending on the column.

```
.columns(
    itemColumn,
    col.column("Quantity",   "quantity",  type.integerType()),
    col.column("Unit price", "unitprice", type.bigDecimalType()))
```